# initialize array in maple

Tags: list, maple

I am trying to generate an array containing the sum of squares from 1 to an arbitrary k. For this, I've currently invoked another function within my loop as:
mylist[k]=function(k) but keep getting an out of bounds error. 
How can I initialize an array of a given size(say n) in Maple?

Answer (score 2):

In Maple, lists and arrays are not the same thing.  Lists are immutable, while arrays are mutable.  It is an anachronism that, for short lists, Maple will allow you to "assign" to an entry as though it were an array.  However, what this actually does is to create a new array, and is extremely inefficient.  That is why, for a sufficiently large list, you see an error when you try to do this.

One correct way to create a list of a given size n is to use the seq command, which creates a sequence.

```
> [seq( i^2, i = 1 .. 10 )];
       [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

(Instead of the literal upper bound "10", you could use the value of a parameter passed to a procedure in which you used this construction.)  The square brackets ([]) around the seq() call turn the resulting sequence into a list data structure.

If what you really need is a (mutable) array, then use the Array constructor in much the same way.

```
> Array( [seq(i^2,i=1..10)] );
       [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

There is an alternative syntax, though, which avoids creating the intermediate list:

```
> Array( 1 .. 10, i -> i^2 );
       [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

(Note that the pretty-printed output for lists and arrays appears the same; don't let that confuse you.)

You should be able to replace the squaring map (i ->i^2) that I've used here with a call to your own procedure.